# Software/drivers to add CEC support for HDMI in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, hp-elitebook

Is there any way to allow my PC to control my TV via HDMI CEC commands?

I'm looking to use this on an HP EliteBook 8530p, with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650 video adapter, running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if an implementation of CEC via software is possible without some videocard BIOS hacking, or hardware implementation.  Everything I have found seems to indicate that it does: 
 
http://www.solid-run.com/mw/index.php/CEC_%28Consumer_Electronics_Control%29_over_HDMI 
http://rainshadowtech.com/default_files/HDMICECUSB.htm

There seems to be speculation about some laptops/motherboards that including this type of thing out of the box; this isn't too helpful in your case, though.